# Why does Mathquill implement a faked text input area with JS instead of building on top of `contenteditable`?

Tags: mathquill

In [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/), the field in which you type is implemented with JS. Even the cursor is just a `span` that blinks.

Why does Mathquill do this instead of building on top of `contenteditable`?